# Databinding with an adapter that has more than one ViewHolder

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-viewholder

I have an adapter with more than one Layout those it has more than one view holder, the view holders all have a bind function that contains the same code I want to create a BaseViewHolder class that contains that function and it's code and implement it on the other view holders. However, since inside of the function the binding object of the layouts is used i can't seem to find a way to define that binding object as a general object and than initialize it according to the corresponding view holder!

These are my view holder classes:

```
class FirstViewHolder(private val binding: FirstViewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(myData: MyData) {
        binding.datas= myData
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
}
class SecondViewHolder(private val binding: SecondViewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(myData: MyData) {
        binding.datas= myData
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
```

In short I want to somehow create a base class that has the bind function so that I won't have redundancy in my code!

Comment: Implement `getItemViewType(position)` in your `ViewHolder.Adapter` class.

Answer (score 0):

Since databinding creates binding class for every layout, there's no inheritance.
In this case you could use general setting of variable via `binding.setVariable(BR.something, data)`.

So in your case it would be:

```
fun bind(myData: MyData) {
    binding.setVariable(BR.datas, myData)
    binding.executePendingBindings()
}
```

And then in your layout don't forget to add the variable.